# I2C Sensor detected but not responding

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, i2c

I got a SFM3000 flow sensor and want to start off with reading the serial number. I did that with the SHT85 before and was successful. Besides increasing the voltage to 5V and replacing the registers everything is basically the same.
Via i2cdetect I can see the device.
I can send command to the device but I cannot read.

I tried different smbus packages and accessed the sensor directly using i2cget/set. But I did not succeed. I tested the sensor on an FTDI U232H and everything worked as expected. Might there be a problem with the Raspberry?

This is what I tried:

```py
    from smbus import SMBus
    import time
    bus = SMBus(1)
    bus.write_i2c_block_data(0x40, 0x31, [0xAE])
    time.sleep(0.0005)
    bus.read_byte_data(0x40, 6)
```

I receive a RemoteIO error.

Comment: I only know that powering sensors with 5V on a Raspberry Pi can lead to problems and may even damage the Raspberry Pi as it is based on 3.3V.